# it's always return null setState()

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I m uploading an image in firebase storage and downloading URL to retrieve image later.
I have added Screenshot and more code.
In print(url) working fine and when passing the value URL to storenewuser function it stores null

```
This is the upload function:
```

```
Future uploadPic() async{
    String filename = phoneNumber;
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("User Profile Image").child(filename);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_Image);
    var downUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url = downUrl.toString();
    print(url);
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      ImageUrl=url;
    });
  }
```

```
SignUp and storing usersdata:
```

```
void Signup() async{
    if(_key.currentState.validate()){
      FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: Email, password: Password).then((signedInUser){
        uploadPic();
        UserManagement().storeNewUser(Name,Email,phoneNumber,ImageUrl,RollNumber,Course,Semester,signedInUser.user, context);
      }).catchError((e){
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
          content: Text(e.message),
        );
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        print(e);
      });
    }
    else{
      print("NULL");
    }
  }

storeNewUser(Name,Email/*,password*/,phonenumber,ImageUrl,rollnumber,course,sem,user,context){
    Firestore.instance.collection('/users').document(user.uid).setData({
      'Name' : Name,
      'Email' : Email,
      'Image Url' : ImageUrl,
      'Phone Number' : phonenumber,
      'Roll Number' : rollnumber,
      'College' : 'Siliguri Institute of Technology',
      'Course' : course,
      'Semester' : sem
    }).then((value){
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpCompletePage()));
    }).catchError((e){
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text(e.message),
      );
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    });
  }
```

Database:

[image]

Storage:

[image]

Comment: add ur firebase storage

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have added Screenshot. I think the problem is in ```if``` statement because ```print(url)``` is working fine

Comment: that's your firestore database, add a screenshot of ur firesbase storage

Comment: Your setState syntax is wrong

Comment: @PrithweeDas , that's why I m here.

Comment: You don't need to call setState if you aren't updating the User Interface. just assign ImageUrl = url; And could you please upload the code of updating/writing the data in the firestore.

Comment: after removing setState it does the same.

Comment: I m getting this error after changing
 ```Future uploadPic() async{
    String filename = phoneNumber;
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("User Profile 
    Photo").child(filename);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_Image);
    var downUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
     url = downUrl.toString();
    print(url);
    setState(() {
      ImageUrl=url;
      print(ImageUrl);
    });
  }```
Error:```setState() called after dispose()```
Help!

Comment: @PeterHaddad Help!

Comment: @JagrajSingh Help!!

Comment: can you please add an image of your firebase storage as asked by peter haddad above. It will help us better understand and solve your query

Comment: Don't use setstate and try putting await before uploadPic() call.

Comment: @StackOverflow I  have already done that.

Comment: @JagrajSingh, as commented above, I have already tried this.

Comment: Cool, please make sure you update your code in the question every time you change it in your pc, also add info about what you have edited. Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change

```
uploadPic();
```

to

```
await uploadPic();
```

:)